# Jade Run error when making changes to a file within react-fullstack

Tags: reactjs, pug, yeoman

I have started a react-fullstack project with yeoman. There is a watcher that updates the jade file when I make changes to it, without me saving. My console looks like this, as you can imagine:

```
[BS] File changed: build/content/index.jade
[BS] File changed: build/content/index.jade
[BS] File changed: build/content/index.jade
[BS] File changed: build/content/index.jade
[BS] File changed: build/content/index.jade
[BS] File changed: build/content/index.jade
[BS] File changed: build/content/index.jade
[BS] File changed: build/content/index.jade
[BS] File changed: build/content/index.jade
[BS] File changed: build/content/index.jade
```

However, whenever it does make a change, an error comes up in the `Run` section of Webstorm 10:

```
/usr/local/bin/jade index.jade

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:939
  throw err;
  ^

SyntaxError: Assigning to rvalue (5:0)
    at Parser.pp.raise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:937:13)
    at Parser.pp.checkLVal (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1216:12)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:193:22)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:152:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:134:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:112:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExpression (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:86:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1728:23)
    at Parser.pp.parseTopLevel (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1644:21)
    at Parser.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1614:17)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This message pops up in the Run window whenever the file is changed, however it doesn't seem to cause actual problems with updating the file.

Have you experienced this error? How can I prevent this error appearing, and why is it related to acorn.js?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You should remove `---` from the codes which is located at the beginning of *.jade files .

For example you can see it in the index.jade :

```html
---
title: React.js Starter Kit
component: ContentPage
---
div.row
  div.col-sm-4
h3 Runtime Components
dl
```